# popViewController problem in tableViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

In my app delegate I have a `navigationController` property.
In my first view I have some buttons and tapping them will make another view appear when it is pushed on `navController`.

In this new view there is another button to open a `UITableViewController` by pushing it on the `navController`.

The problem is in the last view, `UITableViewController`, in fact in `viewDidLoad`, if I have no data, I try to pop it off the `navigationController` but my app crashes.

However, if I connect the pop to a button it works great.

I reference my app delegate instance in order to `popViewControllerAnimated:`, so what is the problem?

Comment: How are you getting the app delegate? Via something like `MyApplicationDelegate *appDelegate = (MyApplicationDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's wrong with the code, can you post your viewDidLoad method?

Also, is it possible to check whether your table will have data BEFORE you push the tableView onto the nav stack?  That would be a much cleaner UI, rather than showing and then immediately popping a view.  If there is no data, disable the button that launches the table view.